# Which url do I use in a test script when using K6 in github

Tags: spring, k6

Im currently looking into K6 to stress test our api. For this I want to set up a github action to run a stress test before deploying to production.

The issue is that in all guides I found for this, the user is using some url pointing to some webpage and not using the api that should be testet.

Is it even possible to do what I want?
What is the correct way here?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry. You want to be able to inject the base URL of the system you are testing dynamically? If so, you can do that through environment variables, see https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/environment-variables/

Comment: What I need is to test the api before it is deployed. I need some guidance on how I can accomplish this or if it is not possible, what are other options I could pursue

Comment: This is difficult to answer, sorry. It completely depends on your system that you are testing. In general, if it's something simple, you can spin up a local HTTP server with your app and pass its URL to the k6 script.

Comment: Is this possible during a github action? Or do I need a server to host the api during this time? the only idea I have is to put the stress test as a requirement for merging to prod and using the stage environment as target for the stress test

Comment: You probably can use something like service containers to spin up your app and then test it: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers